# Prevent inner form from submitting but submit outer form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm using ASP.Net (not my first choice) so all server-side controls are inside the master template's `<form id='frmMain'>` form.

In code that's inserted into that template, I have an `<asp:UpdatePanel>` and within that, a few `<input type='reset' />` elements that need to only reset certain values, so I have those values in inner `<form>` tags.

When one of the inner forms submits, it checks its validity and then does its default GET and the outer form never has a chance to do its thing.  In order to keep the validation, I thought to do:

```
function doSubmit(e) {
    if (this.checkValidity()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        frmMain.submit();
    }

    // don't preventDefault here because validation is taking place with
    // nice UI
}

$(function () {
     $('form:not(#frmMain)').on('submit', doSubmit);
});
```

Unfortunately, triggering `frmMain`'s submit doesn't work with `UpdatePanel`s, and the whole page posts pack rather than doing the async jig.

So I removed the manual calling of `submit()` and hoped that clicking the button would cause two events, one for each form, but that is not the case.  If I call `preventDefault()` the outer form never sees the event.  If I don't call `preventDefault()` the inner form submits before the outer form can do anything.

Is there a way around this?

Yes, I could change the reset inputs to buttons and use javascript to reset just the values I need to, negating the need for the inner forms, but I'm a purist and want to see if it can be done the "way it was meant to" before Microsoft screwed it all up.

Comment: It is invalid HTML to have a form inside a form. The result of that on the client will be the result of non–standard error correction. Move the "inner" form to outside the "outer" form.

Comment: Instead of an "inner" form, consider using a [*fieldset*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-fieldset-element) element to group the elements you wish to treat differently and to reset them. You could also just use a class value to select them.